# Are omitted for duplicate dependencies still vulnerable?

Tags: dependencies, dependency-management

Let's say I have a dependency version declaration of 5.5.3

And somewhere there's a nested transitive dependency version 5.2.1, which contains a vulnerability. But this is overridden by the declared version 5.5.3.

When running a dependency tree, all I see is the 5.5.3 version. When running a verbose dependency tree, in a couple places I see 5.5.3 - version managed from 5.2.1; omitted for duplicate

Can the vulnerability for 5.2.1 still be exploited? Or is it not an issue, since the 5.5.3 version is overriding it?